# slow performance in ubuntu and sometimes stuck

Tags: performance

I recently installed Ubuntu 13.04 i386 and everything works fine expect the speed of my OS performance. I had Windows 7 before and everything works great but after I installed Linux when I login to my account I don't know why sometimes it is stuck or has low speed.

PC Details:

- Lenovo 3000 n100
- Cpu core 2 due 1.6 GHz
- Ram: 2 GB
- Graphic: 1 GB Geforce 7200
- HDD: Seagate SATA 500 GB

Thanks guys.

Comment: GeForce 7200 is quite old. You should be using Xubuntu, or Ubuntu 12.04 with Unity2d.

Answer (score 0):

With those machine specifications you should switch to Lubuntu. As mikewhatever said, the 7200 is an old card and won't support much of the Unity effects. You'll note the difference of performance between Lubuntu and Ubuntu.